# Rust Mutex is not working when using a callback function from multiple C threads created by `fork`

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex, ffi

I am using the C library Cuba which uses a callback function that is called from multiple threads created in C. The Cuba parallelization is based on the `fork`/`wait` POSIX functions instead of pthreads ([arxiv.org/abs/1408.6373](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.6373)). It gives the current thread in the `core` parameter.

I am trying to log results from this callback function to a screen and a file. If I use `println!` I get expected output, but if I use `slog` the output is mangled when I use a `Mutex` drain. If I use the `async` drain I get no output at all.

Is the `Mutex` not locking since it can't see the function is actually called from another thread? I tried to recreate the problem with Rust threads, but couldn't. Preferably I'd like to get the `async` drain to work.

Below is an example program that gives the problematic behaviour. The callback gets the last parameter of the `vegas` function as one of its arguments. This is a vector of clones of loggers. This way, each core should have its own copy of the logger:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate slog;
extern crate cuba;
extern crate slog_term;

use slog::Drain;

// this function is called from different c threads
// `core` indicates which thread
fn integrand(
    _x: &[f64],
    _f: &mut [f64],
    loggers: &mut Vec<slog::Logger>,
    _nvec: usize,
    core: i32,
) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    info!(loggers[core as usize], "A\nB\nC");

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let decorator = slog_term::TermDecorator::new().build();
    let drain = slog_term::CompactFormat::new(decorator).build();
    let drain = std::sync::Mutex::new(drain).fuse();

    let log = slog::Logger::root(drain, o!());

    let mut integrator = cuba::CubaIntegrator::new(integrand);
    integrator.set_cores(10, 1000); // set 10 cores

    integrator.vegas(
        1,
        1,
        cuba::CubaVerbosity::Progress,
        0,
        vec![log.clone(); 11],
    );
}
```

Output:

```
C 
INFO Mar 26A
B
C 10:27
:42.195 MarINFO 26  10:27A
B
C:42.195
 MarINFO 26  10:27A
B
C:42.195
 INFO A
B
C
Mar 26 10:27:42.196 INFO A
B
C
Mar 26 10:27:42.196 INFO A
B
C
```

Comment: Try to replace `log.clone()` (cloning root logger) with `log.new(o!())` (build a child logger). ([Logger::new](https://docs.rs/slog/2.4.1/slog/struct.Logger.html#method.new) docs)

Comment: This does not help unfortunately. Explicitly creating new child loggers (`vec![log.new(o!()), log.new(o!()),...]` also does not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Cuba C library [has this to say](http://www.feynarts.de/cuba/):

> Windows users: Cuba 3 and up uses `fork(2)` to parallelize the execution threads. This POSIX function is not part of the Windows API, however, and is furthermore used in an essential way such that it cannot be worked around simply with `CreateProcess` etc. The only feasible emulation seems to be available through Cygwin.

Here's a reproduction of the code. We `fork` and then the child and the parent attempt to hold the mutex while printing stuff out. A `sleep` is inserted to encourage the OS scheduler to try other threads:

```
use nix::unistd::{fork, ForkResult}; // 0.13.0
use std::{sync::Mutex, thread, time::Duration};

fn main() {
    let shared = Mutex::new(10);

    match fork() {
        Ok(ForkResult::Parent { .. }) => {
            let max = shared.lock().unwrap();
            for _ in 0..*max {
                println!("Parent");
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
            }
        }
        Ok(ForkResult::Child) => {
            let max = shared.lock().unwrap();
            for _ in 0..*max {
                println!("Child");
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
            }
        }
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ cargo run

Parent
Child
Parent
Child
Child
Parent
Child
Parent
Child
Parent
Child
Parent
Child
Parent
Child
Parent
Child
Parent
Child
Parent
```

Using `fork` with threads is *really* a pain to deal with; I distinctly remember hunting down terrible problems related to this before. Two resources I found that go in depth:

- [Mutexes And fork()ing In Shared Libraries](https://brauner.github.io/2018/03/04/locking-in-shared-libraries.html)
- [Synchronization, Part 1: Mutex Locks](https://github.com/angrave/SystemProgramming/wiki/Synchronization,-Part-1:-Mutex-Locks)

The latter says (emphasis mine):

> Can I create mutex before fork-ing?
>
> Yes - however the child and parent process will **not share virtual memory and each one will have a mutex independent of the other**.
>
> (Advanced note: There are advanced options using shared memory that allow a child and parent to share a mutex if it's created with the correct options and uses a shared memory segment. See [procs, fork(), and mutexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172541/procs-fork-and-mutexes))

---

> If I use the async drain I get no output at all.

See also:

- [Why doesn't a lazy_static slog::Logger print until a non-static logger is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47342036/155423)

---

I would **not** trust the Cuba Rust library. There are two main points:

1. If there are threads being created, the user data generic type should have either a `Sync` or `Send` bound on it, restricting to only types that are safe to share / transfer the data between threads.
2. The user data passed to the `integrand` function should **not** be a `&mut`. A fundamental Rust concept is that there can only be a single mutable reference to any piece of data at any time. Cuba trivially allows you to circumvent this.

Here's an attempted reproduction of the Cuba Rust and C libraries:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate slog;

use slog::Drain;

fn integrand(loggers: &mut Vec<slog::Logger>, core: i32) {
    info!(loggers[core as usize], "A\nB\nC\n{}", core);
}

fn main() {
    let decorator = slog_term::TermDecorator::new().build();
    let drain = slog_term::CompactFormat::new(decorator).build();
    let drain = std::sync::Mutex::new(drain).fuse();

    let log = slog::Logger::root(drain, o!());

    let logs = vec![log.clone(); 11];

    cuba_repro(logs, integrand);
}

use std::{ffi::c_void, thread};

type Integrand<T> = fn(&mut T, i32);

fn cuba_repro<T>(mut user_data: T, mut integrand: Integrand<T>) {
    // From the `vegas` method
    let user_data_ptr = &mut user_data as *mut _ as *mut c_void;
    let integrand_ptr = &mut integrand as *mut _ as *mut c_void;

    unsafe { cuba_repro_ffi::<T>(user_data_ptr, integrand_ptr) }
}

unsafe fn cuba_repro_ffi<T>(user_data: *const c_void, integrand: *const c_void) {
    let user_data = FfiDoesNotCareAboutSendOrSync(user_data);
    let integrand = FfiDoesNotCareAboutSendOrSync(integrand);

    let threads: Vec<_> = (0..4).map(move |i| {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            // C doesn't care about this pedantry
            let user_data = &mut *(user_data.0 as *const T as *mut T);
            let integrand = &mut *(integrand.0 as *const Integrand<T> as *mut Integrand<T>);

            // From the `c_integrand` function
            let k: &mut T = &mut *(user_data as *mut _);
            let _ignored = integrand(k, i);
        })
    }).collect();

    for t in threads { t.join().unwrap() }
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct FfiDoesNotCareAboutSendOrSync<T>(T);
unsafe impl<T> Send for FfiDoesNotCareAboutSendOrSync<T> {}
unsafe impl<T> Sync for FfiDoesNotCareAboutSendOrSync<T> {}
```

I had to make *numerous* changes to get the Rust compiler to ignore the huge amount of unsafety and rule-breaking that the Cuba library and related FFI is performing.

This code example *does* actually print out 4 log statements each in order, so this is not a complete answer. However, I'm fairly certain that the Cuba library is triggering undefined behavior, which means that any outcome is possible, including apparently working.

Comment: I wrote the Rust cuba bindings, and I know it's not perfect. I didn't find a better way to get some form of memory safety other than letting the user use the core id that the C cuba library hands over. Do you think the issue is in the bindings or in the way that Cuba handles its multithreading? Regarding async, I think the issue is a concurrent memory access issue since my program runs for several minutes and should generate quite some output.

Comment: @BenRuijl I don't know enough about the underlying code to really provide effective guidance. How are Cuba's threads started? If they aren't via pthreads (or equivalent OS mechanism that Rust is using for `thread::spawn`), I could totally see that the `Mutex` wouldn't lock as expected because bookkeeping data wasn't set up correctly on whatever thread it was using.

Comment: @BenRuijl *I didn't find a better way to get some form of memory safety* — if you expose memory unsafety to your users, you need to mark your functions unsafe and explain how the users are intended to avoid the unsafety. Making the code appear safe when it isn't does a disservice to everyone.

Comment: Apparently the Cuba parallelization is based on the fork/wait POSIX functions instead of pthreads (https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.6373). Do you have an idea how I can make it apparent to Rust that the callback function is called from different forks?

Comment: Thanks for your update. I suppose logging to different files is the easiest option then...